# Why does my program only gets part of web page source?

Tags: java, php, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a program to pull the source code of a webpage and save it to a .txt file. It works if done with just one at a time, but when I go through a loop of say 100 pages all of a sudden each page source starts to get cut off between 1/4 and 3/4 of the way through (seems to be arbitrary).  Any ideas on why or how I would go about solving this?

Initial thoughts where that the loop is going too fast for the java (I am running this java from a php script) but then thought that it technically shouldn't be going to the next item until the current condition was finished anyway.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class selectout {

public static BufferedReader read(String url) throws Exception{
    return new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            new URL(url).openStream()));}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader reader = read(args[0]);
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String thenum = args[1];
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(thenum+".txt");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    while (line != null) {

          out.write(line);
          out.newLine();
        //System.out.println(line);
        line = reader.readLine(); }}
}
```

The PHP is a basic `mysql_query` `while(fetch_assoc)` grab the url from the database, then run `system("java -jar crawl.jar $url $filename");`

Then, it `fopen` and `fread` the new file, and finally saves the source to database (after `escaping_strings` and such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close your output streams after you finish writing each file. After your while loop, call out.close(); and fstream.close();

Answer (score 0):

You must flush the stream and close it.

```
finally{  //Error handling ignored in my example
    fstream.flush();  
    fstream.close();  
}
```